# AdHoc network for Nexus 5

Tags: android, network-programming, adhoc

I would like to create a pure adhoc network using Nexus 5 devices. By pure adhoc network, I mean that the devices should be able to communicate even after the access point has been turned off. I aim to create a peer to peer network to share content among devices. I have checked a number of questions related to this and have not found anything concrete. If anybody has had success doing this, please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Standard IEEE IBSS mode (ad-hoc mode) has been disabled by google, for whatever reason. I use [cyanogenmod](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=hammerhead) for Nexus 5 which has this feature enabled PLUS an option to create ad hoc networks in the settings app. I think they even added an option to the WiFiConfiguration API, but I haven't tried myself. This should get you going.